# How to copy my Related Products to Upsell Products

Tags: magento-1.9, database, related-products, up-sells

i- need to change relaeted products in upsell products . 
any suggestion how to do fast ? 
our shop have more than 35k products 
now we have create related products but we need to change in upsell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a MYSQL script. However I would test the script below locally first and backup the relevant database tables beforehand. I have tested this on a vanilla install of Magento 1.9.2.

So the product relationship of related/upsell/crossell and also configurable products (they have a few more tables) are all stored in the database table "catalog_product_link".

They are distinguished between the 4 types in the column "link_type_id". So in order to switch related products to upsells, we just need to update this column for related products.

Note the id's of the different types are stored in "catalog_product_link_type" database table.

So this MYSQL script below will **update all** related products to upsells.

```
UPDATE catalog_product_link
SET link_type_id = 4
WHERE link_type_id = 1;
```